# what's the different between -mtune=i486 and -arch=i486

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I have an old code need compiled with `-m486` flag in `GCC`. 
But there is no that flag. Then I found `-mtune=i486` and `-arch=i486`
I have read this [page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options).
But still don't know which is the best one for `-m486`?

Comment: You probably could at first drop simply `-m486`

Comment: Note that old GCC options pages, such as [this one for GCC 3.6.6](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html), explain that `-m486` was a synonym for `-mcpu=i486`, which was later deprecated in favor of `-mtune=i486`/`-march=i486`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-march` option defines the list of instructions that may be used, the `-mtune` option modifies the optimization process afterwards.

You would normally use `-march` to specify the minimum requirements, and `-mtune` to optimize for what the majority of users have.

For example, the IA32 architecture defines various instructions for string handling and repetition of instructions. On the 386 and 486, these are faster and smaller than explicit assembler code because the instruction fetch and decode stages can be skipped, while on newer models, these instructions clog up the instruction pipeline as each processing step is immediately dependent on the previous, so the CPU's parallel execution functionality goes to waste.

Linux distributions typically use `-march=i486 -mtune=i686` to ensure that you can still install and run on a 486, but as the majority of users have modern CPUs, the focus is on making it run optimally for these.